# What is difference between translate and replace in XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I was going through some XSLT functions and came across two majorly named as `translate` and `replace`, I understood that, by the end of the day, job of both the functions is replacing some content on declared entity (please enlighten me more on this).

Also I was writing an XSLT where in I want to replace a single value with a bunch of values like below.

```
<div class="translate">
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(current(),' ', 'XXXXX')"/>
        </div>
        <div class="replace">
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(current(),' ', 'XXXXX')"/>
        </div>
```

The `translate` is adding only one `X`, though I've added `XXXXX`, where as the replace is working fine.

Can someone please let me know what's happening in the background?

Here is a working Sample http://xsltransform.net/6rewNxE/2

Comment: Well, read the spec, https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate and https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-replace.

Answer (score 14):

### Difference between translate() and replace()

- Use **[translate($s, $mapFrom, $mapTo)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-translate)** to change occurrences of
  ***characters*** given in `$mapFrom` to those in equivalent positions in `$mapTo`.
- Use **[replace($s, $pattern, $replacement)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace)** to change
  occurrences of ***matching substrings*** given by a matching
  `$pattern` regex to a `$replacement` string.

Note that `translate()` is available starting from XPath 1.0; `replace()`, from XPath 2.0.

**Therefore, in your example:**

- **`translate()`** will replace each `' '` (space) character with a '`X`'
  character, because the `$mapTo` character that corresponds to the
  equivalent position of `' '` (space) in the `$mapFrom` is an '`X`'.
- **`replace()`** will replace the first `" "` (single-space) substring
  with a `"XXXXX"`, because the literal `$pattern` matches the first
  occurrence of a `" "` (single-space) substring and replaces it with
  the full `$replacement` string.

Answer (score 11):

The replace-function replaces one string with another in a string. If there is the String "abcacb" and you replace "ab" with "xy" you get "xycacb".

```
replace("abcacb","ab","xy") = "xycacb"
```

The translate function replaces the string charcter by character. The first character in the "please-replace-this-string" will be replaced with the first character in "replace-with-this-string"
So if there is the String "abcacb" and you translate "ab" with "xy" you get "xycxcy".

`translate("abcacb","ab","xy") = "xycxcy"`

**For your case:**

- replace: ' ' will be replaced with 'XXXXX'
- translate ' ' will be replaced with the first character of 'XXXXXX' which is 'X'

The explanations of the Oracle-SQL functions might also help (basically the same):

- [replace()](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php)
- [translate()](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/translate.php)

Comment: According to the replace() Oracle link you provided, your replace() example isn't quite right.   instead of = "xycabc" it should be "xycacb"